# Apache + WSGI + Trac: Random HTTP 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, wsgi, trac

I'm having a difficult time troubleshooting seemingly random `HTTP 500 Internal Server Error` problems with a new Trac 1.0.3 installation.  Environment:

- Debian 7.8
- Apache 2.2.22
- Python 2.7.3
- Genshi 0.6
- Sqlite 3.7.13
- WSGI 3.3

I have Apache `LogLevel debug` - this didn't reveal anything to me.  I have Trac (`trac.ini`) logging as follows:

```
[logging]
log_file = /var/trac/log/trac.log
log_level = DEBUG
log_type = file
```

Again, nothing jumps out at me.  I am capturing WSGI/Trac `environ` dictionary - nothing revealing there.  In `trac.wsgi` I set up tracking of requests and responses as specified in https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/DebuggingTechniques#Tracking_Request_and_Response.  This essentially yields the same as my crude logging of `environ` dict but with this technique it is pretty printed.

When others and I click around in Trac maybe 10% of the time we get what seems to be a random `HTTP 500 Internal Server Error` (page can vary)... then refresh the page and it loads.  None of my efforts thus far have captured any signs of the 500 in logs - I see nothing but `200 Ok` or `304 Not Modified`.

Your assistance in troubleshooting in much appreciated.  Thanks.

**UPDATE 1**

To clear any concerns or confusion for those that may get hung up on *where* data is being logged... WSGI Request and Response Tracking (see https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/DebuggingTechniques#Tracking_Request_and_Response link I originally posted) logs to Apache's error log (the page says "The output from the middleware would end up in the Apache error log for the virtual host, or if no virtual host specific error log file, in the main Apache error log file.").

**UPDATE 2**

I discovered that when a user receives an `HTTP 500`, which is logged by Apache as expected in `ssl_access.log`, there is no corresponding (Apache *or* WSGI) log entry in `errors.log`.  So, when the error occurs either the request is not making it from Apache to WSGI or if it is WSGI is failing miserably thus no log.

Ideas on how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: You checked the apache log and there is nothing? I'd check my v-host config to see whether the apache log is located somewhere else then.

Comment: Sorry - to clarify - data is being logged to Apache `error.log` and `ssl_access.log`, just nothing that aids me in resolving the issue.

Comment: You see 200 in an error log? I think you're looking in the wrong place.

Comment: It's only there due to how the WSGI logging (it's not a "normal" Apache log entry) for this debugging effort is set up; I assure you I am looking at the correct logs.

Comment: See `UPDATE 1` for more info regarding log data.